# semantic-release publishing tags to wrong channel

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow, semantic-versioning, semantic-release

I am using semantic-release for our .Net Core solution.
Semantic-release is used as part of the CI pipeline on GitLab repository.

This is my .releaserc.json

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    ["@semantic-release/changelog", {
      "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/exec", {
      "publishCmd": "./publish.sh ${nextRelease.version}"
    }],
    "@semantic-release/gitlab"
  ],
  "branches": [
      "master",
      {"name": "develop", "channel": "beta", "prerelease": "beta"},
      {"name": "release", "channel": "RC", "prerelease": "RC"}
  ]
}
```

As you can see I am using simplified GitFlow.
I have a `master` branch, single `release` branch used for publishing release candidates and `develop` branch with the latest development code. There are also feature branches created from `develop` but they are not versioned.

The problem I am having is that once I merge the code from `develop` to `release` any commit done to `develop` branch will result in semantic-release not able to find the last tag create before the merge to `release`.

Let me try to explain what is happening.
Merge to `develop`, using squash, is created for a feature branch (which was created from `develop`) with commit message `feat(Products): Add tag support` this commit will result in new version `v1.10.0-beta.11`.
Next, I will merge the `develop` branch to `release`, this will result in `1.10.0-RC.1` version being created.
Next, I will do a new commit to `develop` branch which will result in semantic-release not being able to create a new version.

```
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag v1.10.0-beta.10 associated with version 1.10.0-beta.10 on branch develop
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 2 commits since last release
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: feat(Products): One commit before Add tag support
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The release type for the commit is minor
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: feat(Products): Add tag support
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The release type for the commit is patch
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 2 commits complete: minor release
...
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "prepare" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "prepare" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[11:09:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: Error: Command failed with exit code 128: git tag v1.10.0-beta.11 a1ee6896485641d039f1816efcc0e30dce7139e8
fatal: tag 'v1.10.0-beta.11' already exists
...
```

All future commits to `develop` will fail. The only solution is to merge `release` to `master` branch.
If I merge `develop` to `release` again. This will happen:

```
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag v1.10.0-beta.11 associated with version 1.10.0-beta.11 on branch release
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 1 commits since last release
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: fix(bug): Some bug fixed
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The release type for the commit is patch
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 1 commits complete: patch release
[9:57:53 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
...
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "publish" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/gitlab] › ℹ  Published GitLab release: v1.10.0-beta.12
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "publish" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "success" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "success" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[9:59:02 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Published release 1.10.0-beta.12 on RC channel
```

It will publish beta release on RC channel.

To me, it looks like a configuration issue or maybe branching model issues.
Any help would be appreciated!

Note:
Initially I wanted to use the vanilla GitFlow branching model, but I ran in to even more issues with semantic-release, so I simplified it a bit.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Have you found solution? Looks like this may be related: https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1708